# Understanding a Struct in TCL C API

Tags: c, struct, tcl, function-pointers, typedef

Came across the following struct which is defined in tcl.h, the C language API for Tcl.

```
typedef struct {
char *result;
Tcl_FreeProc *freeProc;
int errorLine;
} Tcl_Interp;

typedef void Tcl_FreeProc(char *blockPtr);
```

In the documentation, they have mentioned the following on the struct member fields:

> The result field points to the string that represents the result or error message, and the freeProc field tells how to dispose of the storage for the string when it is not needed anymore.
>
> Tcl_SetResult's freeProc argument specifies how the Tcl system is to manage the storage for the result argument. If Tcl_SetResult or Tcl_SetObjResult are called at a time when interp holds a string result, they do whatever is necessary to dispose of the old string result.
>
> freeProc can take three main values, TCL_STATIC, TCL_DYNAMIC or TCL_VOLATILE.
>
> If freeProc is not one of the values TCL_STATIC, TCL_DYNAMIC, and TCL_VOLATILE, then it is the address of a procedure that Tcl should call to free the string. This allows applications to use non-standard storage allocators.

The fields are defined in the tcl.h header:

```
#define TCL_VOLATILE ((Tcl_FreeProc *) -1)
#define TCL_STATIC   ((Tcl_FreeProc *) 0)
#define TCL_DYNAMIC  ((Tcl_FreeProc *) free)
```

What I can't understand is how they have defined the three values. Shouldn't it be a function pointer with void return and one char* argument? how can it take values like 0 and -1?

Comment: Before calling the function, you have to compare `freeProc` against those constants. If it's **not** one of those constants, then it's a function that can be called.

Comment: Be aware that those fields have gone away (or rather gone into the shrouded internals) in later versions of Tcl. Use `Tcl_SetResult()` to set the `freeProc` field (as well as result) and `Tcl_ResetResult()` to call it. Those two functions have been around for decades now; there is no reason to ever want to have direct access to the fields themselves any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Tcl_FreeProc is a pointer, as a pointer it can be assigned any value.

In this case the pointer gets assigned either -1, 0 or a real address and since -1 and 0 are not valid addresses is used to check whether the freeProc points to a function (which needs to be called) or has one of those values and as such no free function is needed.

EDIT: rephrased it for Chris.

Comment: 0 cast to a pointer value isn't "unlikely to be (a) real address" - it's very specifically a null pointer constant. -1 on the other hand is just a "hope this doesn't clobber anything" address.

Comment: @ChrisLutz depends a bit what hardware you are playing with.

Comment: No, it doesn't. The C standard states that when the literal 0 is interpreted as a pointer constant, it is a null pointer. The hardware representation may not be all-bits-0, but to the C programming language 0 is always a null pointer.

Comment: @ChrisLutz: thanks. think I got the idea. so it is a way of determining whether the relevant function should be called or not? If it is a null pointer, nothing done, but if it's a valid address to a function it is called to do the memory clean up.

Comment: So you are saying that I cant put a function at address 0 on a micro controller?

Comment: _I'm_ not saying it, the standard is. 6.3.2.3 paragraph 3 of the C99 standard: "An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type `void *`, is called a null pointer constant. If a null pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a null pointer, is guaranteed to compare unequal to a pointer to any object or function."

Comment: @Chris: Quite so. As it happens, -1 is exceptionally unlikely to be the address of a function on 32-bit architectures and up; the benefits of function alignment are that strong. Of course, that says nothing about smaller machines (low-end embedded, etc.) but Tcl doesn't attempt to target anything smaller than 32-bit systems. I don't think you could _fit_ the object code into a 16-bit machine, even if there was no OS…

Comment: (In fact, I don't think you could fit Tcl's bytecode execution engine on a 16-bit machine, and that's just one component out of many. Even a hybrid machine like the old 8086 with its odd 20-bit addressing wouldn't be large enough to hold a Tcl build.)